# Cannot access Windows share via samba

Tags: ubuntu

I cannot access Window machines via samba service in Ubuntu 16.04. I uninstalled and reinstalled samba service like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove samba*
sudo apt-get purge samba*
```

After this operation I performed:

```
sudo apt install samba samba-common
```

I restarted the machine and then, when I tried to connect:
smb://192.168.... etc the Connect button is inactive and underneath the connection window I have a message that reads "This file server type is not recognized". What went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to install the package `gvfs-backends`

Run this command:

`sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Samba. Samba is the *server* protocol for SMB and serves data in the other direction; with it, Windows can mount shares offered by your Ubuntu 16.04.

You need either `smb-client` or `cifs-utils`/`cifs-tools`. This page details [CIFS utils for Ubuntu 16.04](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/mount-windows-share-ubuntu-16-0-4-lts/) to mount Windows shares.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with the other solution as well. But now I will install the packages just in case. I remember having them installed previously. I am still a beginner in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

After some python like installations smb not worked. it is sorted out by adding below command in terminal

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

and then give an update or sometimes it needs a restart

```
sudo apt-get update
```